# Replacing the page content depending on the place of arrival angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

I need to display a page with texts like:

"Successfully registered by email "

"We have sent an email confirming registration" etc.

All windows would look the same. Only the content would be different. So:

1. Should I create a component for each message or rather one universal where the content will be changed?
2. If the second option - how to do it? What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring one component with @Input() attribute is set with required text you want to display.

```
@Component({
selector: 'loginPage',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
 })
export class LoginPage{
@Input('content') content:any;

constructor() {}
}
```

Now import the component in app.module.ts(declaration and entryCompnent section).
Use component as selector in html file like below.

```
 <div *ngIf="!isEmailConfirm">
 <loginPage [content]="Successfully registered by email"></loginPage>
 </div>

 <div *ngIf="isEmailConfirm">
 <loginPage [content]="We have sent an email confirming registration"></loginPage>
 </div>
```

Declare isEmailConfirm boolean varaible in your parent component like below

```
export class ParentPage{
isEmailConfirm :boolean=false;

constructor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you get the message that need to be displayed from the http response itself that way whatever your needs to be sent can be changed from backend. Oherwise if you are getting some success code in response you need to create a dictionary to associate with respective message.But you should try and some some response from the request itself.

Comment: Could you send me example?

Comment: @Chocho how do you decide what message is to be displayed....there has to be a network http call for the same right?